# Xcode project is locked if using Cordova (Phonegap)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm building an app with Cordova (Phonegap) and installed the Framework and build my project (for iOS and Android) with the `command line tool`.

When I want to open the newly created project with Xcode, I get plenty (like 9-10) of notifications that my project is locked and can't be changed. How (and why should I) can I change the rights for the project with the command line tool or something similar, because I'm also unable to archive my project because of that problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change the owner of the project path to your user.

Example:

My user: dawson

My project path: /work/some_project

Run this:

```
sudo chown -R dawson /work/some_project
```